# Why in django-import-export doesn't work use_bulk?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, oracle12c, django-import-export

I use **`django-import-export 2.8.0`** with **`Oracle 12c`**.
Line-by-line import via *`import_data()`* works without problems, but when I turn on the **`use_bulk=True`** option, it stops importing and does not throw any errors.
Why does not it work?

`resources.py`

```
class ClientsResources(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'surname', 'age', 'is_active')
        batch_size = 1000
        use_bulk = True
        raise_errors = True
```

`views.py`

```
def import_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_format = request.POST['file-format']
        new_employees = request.FILES['importData']

        clients_resource = ClientsResources()
        dataset = Dataset()

        imported_data = dataset.load(new_employees.read().decode('utf-8'), format=file_format)
        result = clients_resource.import_data(imported_data, dry_run=True, raise_errors=True)

        if not result.has_errors():
            clients_resource.import_data(imported_data, dry_run=False)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

`data.csv`

```
id,name,surname,age,is_active
18,XSXQAMA,BEHKZFI,89,Y
19,DYKNLVE,ZVYDVCX,20,Y
20,GPYXUQE,BCSRUSA,73,Y
21,EFHOGJJ,MXTWVST,93,Y
22,OGRCEEQ,KJZVQEG,52,Y
```

**--UPD--**

I used *`django-debug-toolbar`* and saw a very strange behavior with import-queries.

With Admin Panel doesnt work. I [see all importing rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON3wj.png), but next it writes "Import finished, with 5 new and 0 updated clients.", and see this [strange queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5N0l.png)

Then I use import by my form and here simultaneous situation:

**use_bulk** by [django-import-export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj6GB.png) ([more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMPcz.png))

And for comparing my handle [create_bulk()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nunom.png)

**--UPD2--**

I've tried to trail import logic and look what I found:

`import_export/resources.py`

```
   def bulk_create(self, using_transactions, dry_run, raise_errors, batch_size=None):
        """
        Creates objects by calling ``bulk_create``.
        """
        print(self.create_instances)
        try:
            if len(self.create_instances) > 0:
                if not using_transactions and dry_run:
                    pass
                else:
                    self._meta.model.objects.bulk_create(self.create_instances, batch_size=batch_size)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
            if raise_errors:
                raise e
        finally:
            self.create_instances.clear()
```

This print() showed empty list in value.

Comment: `django-import-export` has admin integration - you could try an import using admin integration and see if it works.  You could set a breakpoint on `import_data()` calls and step through to see why it's not persisting.  Add `raise_errors=True` to the second `import_data()` call to see if there is a problem with persisting.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty Thank you. I've added some screens with result of strange import-queries behavior, it use bulk_update insted of bulk_create, and there no any errors. What is it?

Comment: Make sure you are using latest stable version of `django-import-export`; make sure you haven't left `dry_run=False`.  Step through with debug should show the problem.  You can also try using the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) for comparison.

Comment: Also, I don't know if `django-import-export` has been tested under Oracle.  Supported dbs are postgres / mysql.  I suggest google for django & bulk create on Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be due to a bug in the 2.x version of `django-import-export`.  It is fixed in v3.

- The bug is present when running in bulk mode (`use_bulk=True`)
- The logic in `save_instance()` is finding that 'new' instances have `pk` values set, and are then incorrectly treating them as updates, not creates.
- I cannot determine how this would happen. It's possible this is related to using Oracle (though I cannot see how).

Comment: raise_errors set True, no errors.           ||   print(self.update_instances) showed twice: full list and empty list

Comment: so this looks like the process is doing a bulk update instead of create.  See my updated answer.   Are the ids listed in the source file present in your target Clients table?

Comment: OrderedDict([('new', 5), ('update', 0), ('delete', 0), ('skip', 0), ('error', 0), ('invalid', 0)])

Comment: so you are saying that update_instances() is being called, yet instances are being identified as 'new'.  The fastest way to resolve will be to step through with a debugger, or set print() statements.  What happens in [`save_instance()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/033f803c5994ceba9da8b610819ee5b52a630bf7/import_export/resources.py#L460)?  If a new instance has a `pk` field, this would be treated as an `update`.  I can't see how this would happen.  You could try the [beta](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/3.0.0b1/) release to see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, in `save_instance()` going `if instanste.pk -> self.update_instances.append(instance)`

Comment: there debug logs https://pastebin.com/wCXzYrRv

Comment: O gosh, beta solved the problem. It's importing. Thank you.

Comment: np - have updated my answer